# Prevent Breaking On Handled Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I checked all the exceptions for "`Common Language Runtime Exceptions`" on the "ExceptionSettings" window but this time, Visual Studio breaks execution even for exceptions that are inside `try`-`catch` blocks. How can I make it break execution when any kind of exception is encountered but only if not handled inside a `try`-`catch`?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Debug -> Windows -> Exceptions and make sure none of exceptions is checked.

Then VS shouldn't break on any of exceptions.

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019).

For unhadnled exceptions, VS breaks on default, just try this simple code with checked, then unchecked `InvalidCastException` in Exception settings:

```
private void TestMethod()
{
  try
  {
    var i = 0;
    throw new InvalidCastException();
  }
  catch(InvalidCastException ex)
  {
    var j = 0;
  }
  throw new InvalidCastException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it does not resolve what I am asking for. I want to break on every kind of exception but I don't want to break if the exception is handled in a try-catch by me.

Comment: @hakanviv If it's unhandled, then VS will break on it anyway :)